# dyndns and xname.org

Tags: dyndns, dynamic

I have domain name at dyndns. I want to create zone at xname.org. I set up zone for my domain name, and now i try to configure it. In A record field we have 2 parameters - Name and IP. Name it's my domain name, and what IP adress i must input here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> what IP adress i must input here?

Well presumably, that would be the IP address of the webserver that will be servicing this domain. If you don't know your webserver's IP address, then I'd recommend you talk to your webhost's tech support team.

Comment: Thank you for reply. My ip address is dynamic. But it's bind to dyndns